# I need a batch to open an file whenever the workstation is unlocked

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

So the batch file I need has to open an excel file whenever the password is typed to unlock the computer.I know this thing can be done with Task Scheduler but I need a batch file because this action implies multiple workstations.
Thank you!

Comment: You can use the Task Scheduler to run a batch file ...

Comment: And how should i do this on ~40 workstations?

Comment: Use [psexec](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html) to remotetely create tasks with [schtasks](http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html)?

Comment: In a domain environment, you can use group policy preferences to assign scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to open an excel file using command prompt, please check this :

Starts Excel and opens the specified file.

Example

```
excel.exe "c:\My Folder\book1.xlsx"
```

or

```
excel.exe http://MySite/Book1.xlsx
```

For the documentation how to do that please read [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Excel-321cf55a-ace4-40b3-9082-53bd4bc10725). You can create *.bat / *.cmd to open up multiple excel using that command And you can open up multiple file indeed using VBS that you run in command prompt. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854263/what-the-win-cmd-to-open-a-particular-spreadsheet-in-excel) link how to do that.

Hope, this help you out.